# Can I use chrome devtools html formatter standalone?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, browser-automation, pretty-print

Is there a way to use the chrome devtools [html formatter](https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-frontend/blob/ae345f812406ac1927a627f30bc9883b93821faa/front_end/entrypoints/formatter_worker/HTMLFormatter.ts) standalone?

I want to compare 2 html string for differences but ignoring non-significant white-space

I have some html string that I would like to format as in the devtools source pane?
I've tried other formatters like using php DomDocument with preserveWhitespace = false but I still doesn't like the generated output

Or is there a way (using puppeteer or some kind of browser automation) to open a page in chrome, open the devtools, go the the sources pane, select the correct page, click the prettify icon and save the prettified text?